# How to hide a sub view in one of the child views in Recyclerview when clicked outside of the view or anywhere else on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm working on an android application where I have implemented a Recyclerview with few views grouped in each child.(Please view the images linked here),
[RecyclerviewItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NeKy.png). When clicked on the 'More options' icon which is on the rightmost corner, it will make 'actions' layout visible which was invisible. [ActionItemsVisibleWhenMoreOptionsIsClicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYm2H.png). What I want to know is, how to make the 'actions' layout invisible again when user touches/clicks outside of that layout. It may be a click on other item in the Recyclerview or may be a click on outside the Recyclerview.

Below is my layout xml of the Child schema.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/pure_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/task_detail_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/priority_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:background="@color/high" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/task_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4.35"
                android:background="@color/pure_white"
                android:hint="@string/task_description_dummy"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:paddingStart="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/actions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/pure_white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/done_task"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_task" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/edit_task"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_task" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/delete_task"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_task" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/more_options"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/pure_white"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_options" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my Adapter

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Task> tasks;
private Context context;

static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    LinearLayout taskDetailLayout;
    View priorityView;
    TextView taskDescriptionView;
    ImageView moreOptions;
    LinearLayout actions;
    ImageView markTaskCompleted;
    ImageView editTask;
    ImageView deleteTask;

    MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        taskDetailLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.task_detail_layout);
        priorityView = view.findViewById(R.id.priority_view);
        taskDescriptionView = view.findViewById(R.id.task_description);
        moreOptions = view.findViewById(R.id.more_options);
        actions = view.findViewById(R.id.actions);
        markTaskCompleted = view.findViewById(R.id.done_task);
        editTask = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_task);
        deleteTask = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_task);
    }

}

public TaskAdapter(List<Task> items, Context context) {
    this.tasks = items;
    this.context = context;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

public void refreshTaskList(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.task_schema, parent, false);
    return new TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Task currentTask = tasks.get(position);

    if (null != currentTask) {
        String taskDescription = currentTask.getDescription();
        String priority = currentTask.getPriority();
        boolean isTaskCompleted = currentTask.isTaskCompleted();
        int priorityColor = PRIORITY_LOW.equalsIgnoreCase(priority) ? context.getResources().getColor(R.color.low) :
                (PRIORITY_MEDIUM.equalsIgnoreCase(priority) ? context.getResources().getColor(R.color.medium) :
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.high));

        holder.taskDescriptionView.setText(taskDescription);
        holder.priorityView.setBackgroundColor(priorityColor);

        // When user clicks 'More Options' icon show the action icons
        holder.moreOptions.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            holder.actions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.taskDetailLayout.setAlpha(0.7F);
            holder.taskDescriptionView.setAlpha(0.7F);
            holder.taskDetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dim_description_color));
            holder.taskDescriptionView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dim_description_color));
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.right_to_left_anim);
            holder.actions.startAnimation(animation);
        });


        // Mark Task related logic
        // If task is already completed, show done_mark icon and hide edit icon
        if (isTaskCompleted) {
            holder.markTaskCompleted.setOnClickListener(null);
            holder.markTaskCompleted.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_done_mark));
            holder.editTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // When user clicks 'Mark Done' icon show the popup
            holder.markTaskCompleted.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Mark Completed")
                        .setMessage("Nice, Have you completed the task?")
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", (arg0, arg1) -> {
                            TaskHelper.markTaskCompleted(context, currentTask.getId());
                            holder.markTaskCompleted.setOnClickListener(null);
                            holder.markTaskCompleted.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_done_mark));
                            holder.editTask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }).create().show();
                ;
            });
        }

        // Delete task related logic
        // When user clicks 'Delete task' icon
        holder.deleteTask.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Delete task")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure want to delete the task?")
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", (arg0, arg1) -> {
                        new HomeScreenActivity().deleteTask(context, currentTask.getId());
                        holder.actions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }).create().show();
        });

        // Edit task related logic
        holder.editTask.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, AddNewTaskActivity.class);
            editIntent.putExtra(TASK_ID, currentTask.getId());
            context.startActivity(editIntent);
        });

    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks.size();
}
```

}

I need the logic/functionality which can be implemented in Adapter or in an Activity.

Comment: Hey Agniraj, please be mindful of others' time: don't ask others to write code. If the person answering gives you a valid high level description of how to solve the problem, that is an acceptable answer. If they want to also provide with a code example, that's up to them, really. It's extremely unlikely someone can give you copy-pasteable code that will work for you without any changes, anyway.

Comment: Yup..Right @rock3r. I do not need a COPY PASTEABLE code. I just want to know how can we implement it. Because I tried for almost all possible ways I could but nothing worked out for me. Thanks for the complement.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of knowing whether or not to hide the options menu, you could add a flag that keeps track of whether a ViewHolder is 'showing' its options or not. This would at least give you a simple way to hide the menu again if the user taps the 'More options' icon.

In terms of knowing when the user clicked outside of the view... this is more complicated. Since a RecyclerView is a ViewGroup, inside your Activity, you could intercept your RecyclerView's touch events using the [onInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method.

Depending on your layout, you might need to intercept this by other views too, or even create a large dummy view over the entire screen to handle this..

Comment: Appreciate your answer Ryan. Coming to your Point 1. Yes, right. A flag will make it easier to hide the layout when a user clicks the 'more actions' icon again. But it is not necessary that the user will always follow this. So I need a holistic approach which detects the clicks outside of the particular actions layout. Point 2. OnInterceptTouch will handle the touch for entire view if I'm not wrong, how to hide the actions layout in one child when other child is clicked ?